# C# Datagrid (not datagridview): how to sort a column of numbers since all values are stored as Text?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I am fairly new to C#.  I have a datagrid object.  First column is a name column as text of course; all other columns are (below the header row) are numbers.  When I click on one of the column headers to sort that column, I see that is is sorting the numbers as strings since they are stored that way.  How do I get the sorting to sort by numeric value instead?  Do I need to write my own sorting routine? Do I need a converter for that?  If so, can anyone point me to an example of how that is done?

Here is how I am adding the data to my DataGrid:

```
rows = dbm.getDataForRow(tableview, supid, true);
DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
TextBlock tbHeader = new TextBlock();

if (suplier == "All")
    tbHeader.Text = "Suplier ";
else
    tbHeader.Text = "Date";

tbHeader.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(-90);
tbHeader.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
c1.Header = tbHeader;
c1.Binding = new Binding("rowdata[0]");
dg.Columns.Add(c1);
string cellvalue = null;
for (int i = 1; i < columnnames.Count + 1; i++)
{
   tbHeader = new TextBlock();
   c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
   tbHeader.Text = columnnames[i - 1];
   tbHeader.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(-90);
   tbHeader.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
   c1.Header = tbHeader;

   c1.Binding = new Binding("rowdata[" + i + "]");
   // or should I just add the data like c1.Columns.Add(rowdata[i]);
   dg.Columns.Add(c1);
}

dg.ItemsSource = rows;
```

Comment: Convert your strings to numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Use your property as an Int type and not a string object.
you can use ValueConverter in order to display it like you do now.

if you get your data from dataTable you can make sure its an INT type.

```
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("myData");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("numericData", typeof(int)); // this will make sure datagrid is sorting as numeric
    dataTable.Columns.Add("stringData", typeof(String));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("anotherNumericData", typeof(decimal));
    // rest of your code...
    datagrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

another approach:

[Improving Microsoft DataGrid CTP sorting performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/26/improving-microsoft-datagrid-ctp-sorting-performance.aspx)